# Errors in partial fractions decomposition

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I decompose the fraction $\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^3}$ into $$\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^3}=\frac{Ax+B}{(x^2+1)^2}+\frac{Cx+D}{(x^2+1)^3}.$$
From here I found: $A=C=0,$ and $B=-D=1$

Now $$\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^3}=\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}-\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^3}$$

but the right side is not equal to the left side. How is this possible.

And, and similarly another example How is this possible

$$\frac{x^5+1}{x^4(x^2+1)}=\frac{Ax^3+Bx^2+Cx+D}{x^4}+\frac{Ex+F}{x^2+1}.$$

Find, $A=B=C=F=0,$ and $D=E=1$

Now write, $$\frac{x^5+1}{x^4(x^2+1)}=\frac{1}{x^4}+\frac{1}{x^2+1}.$$

but the right side is not equal to the left side. How is this possible.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: In your first example, why do you think the right and left sides are unequal?

Comment: must be equal on both sides, in this case there are

Comment: Your question is quite unclear.Please explain your problems in details.

Comment: @he hehi. "must be equal on both sides". What on Earth does that mean ? What would it be if it was equal only on one side ?

Answer (score 4):

The first expression you got it right, I do the second for you:

$\dfrac{x^5+1}{x^4(x^2+1)}=\dfrac{x^5}{x^4(x^2+1)}+\dfrac{1}{x^4(x^2+1)}=\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}+\dfrac{1+x^2-x^2}{x^4(x^2+1)}=\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}+\dfrac{1+x^2}{x^4(x^2+1)}-\dfrac{x^2}{x^4(x^2+1)}=\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}+\dfrac{1}{x^4}-\dfrac{1}{x^2(x^2+1)}=\dfrac{x}{x^2+1}+\dfrac{1}{x^4}-\dfrac{1}{x^2}+\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}$

Comment: thanks for your answers, now that I saw a little better example, I think that should be written in the form $\frac{x^5+1}{x^4(x^2+1)}=\frac{A}{x}+\frac{B}{x^2}+\frac{C}{x^3}+\frac{D}{x^4}+\frac{Ex+F}{x^2+1}$ 
from where we will have $A=C=0,$ $D=E=F=-B=1$